# war file build by maven commands not working

Tags: maven, jenkins, war

I am building a war file from eclipse it is working fine but when I tried a build a war file in Jenkins by using Maven plugin it is building a war file but it is not working. where exactly I am doing wrong..

i installed ubuntu 16.04
installed java 1.7
installed maven 3.3
installed jenkins
configured jenkins and with java and maven installation path. Given maven cmd 
clean install.
the build is successful and war file is deployed to tomcat 8 container but I am getting an error like
HTTP Status 500 - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
But when I export war file from my eclipse and copy it to tomcat container it is working fine and I followed  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIldJE4tSlA to configure maven project in jenkins.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you are not doing it correctly.

Comment: can please explain how to do it